# ssh -N steals keystrokes

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, terminal, gnome, tty

When I run an ssh session purely for tunnelling purposes, I start it like this:

```
ssh -N -L 5432:localhost:5432 user@host &
```

However, when I do so, about every second keystroke in the terminal where I've done this doesn't work.  Other windows are unaffected.  What is going on?

Details:

- Ubuntu 17.04
- OpenSSH 7.4p1
- GNOME Terminal 3.20.2

I can't think of anything else that may be relevant, but if there is, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start it with the `-f` switch, which will do the same with well-behaved manner:

```
ssh -f -N -L 5432:localhost:5432 user@host
```

It will go to background automatically after authentication or other steps that might require interactivity.